# Rendering action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to render an action in my `application.html.erb` layout file to display it as a modal box using some jquery scripts. I've heard that i can use `render :template => 'spots/new'` but it looks like this method is not rendering an action but just a view file.

**spots#new**

```
def new
  @spot = Spot.new
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@spot) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when i'm trying to render `spots#new` with `render :template => 'spots/new'`, i'm getting `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` error. Have you any idea what am i doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you calling ```render :template => 'spots/new'``` from another controller? another action? or what?

Comment: as i've said, i'm using it in my `application.html.erb` layout file:)

Comment: wat?! why?! i don't get it... you are not using ```yield```?

Comment: I can't use yield for that purpose. I need to render a form in hidden div on every single action of my application (there will be a `Add new spot`link in main menu which will open a modal box with that form). That's why i'm trying to render `spots#new` in my layout file. For regular content, i'm using yield.

Comment: i don't think that you "need" to do it that way. i usually use ajax to render such a template on demand. which makes way more sense. otherwise you would need to do a ```@spot = Spot.new``` on every action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `render :template => 'spots/new'` just renders your view template, it does not call `spots#new`. You should create @spot instance variable before rendering the template.

In your case probably following code will work:

```
<% @spot ||= Spot.new %>
<%= form_for(@spot) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```